# Google Gift - Google play services

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play-services

I am working on Google play services(gift) for android. I running the example provide on Github.com **(Be Generous)**. The example is working fine but there is problem with application notifications. In few devices notification came as the request is received but on some it does not.

Also request notifications and multi player notification is active in Google setting.

Any one know about this??

Comment: Please show some code, and include specific errors you're seeing.

Comment: Which github project was your example?